# Python 2d list value check

Tags: python, list, 2d

The following script generates a 2d list in python:

```
matrix = [[0 for row in range (5)] for col in range (5)]


i = 2
matrix[i][i] = 1
matrix[i+1][i] = 1
matrix[i][i+1] = 1
matrix[i+1][i+1] = 1


for row in matrix:
    for item in row:
        print(item,end="   ")

    print()
    print()
```

The generated 2d list looks like this:

```
0   0   0   0   0   

0   0   0   0   0   

0   0   1   1   0   

0   0   1   1   0   

0   0   0   0   0
```

How can I find if I have a square with the same number (number must be 1) like shown up? The square with the same number must be 2x2

Comment: What was your attempt and where did it fail? Please provide the code and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Added the code for the list generation. I am stuck and I cannot think of any ideas on how to actually check if the values are the same.

Comment: Are you trying to find all indices`(i, j)` of the array, that fulfill certain criteria like `matrix[i][j]==1`?

Comment: No, I just need to find one 2x2 square that has 1s in it. If such square is found the program terminates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can iterate over every element in matrix till we find 1. If we encounter 1 then we can check it's neighbor elements whether it contains 1 or not because if we have not encountered 1 then the matrix it is forming with it's neighbor is not of our interest.

Here's the code for doing it:

```
def check_matrix(i,j):
    if matrix[i][i+1] ==1 and matrix[i+1][j]==1 and matrix[i+1][j+1]==1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        if matrix[i][j] == 1:
            check = check_matrix(i,j)
            if check == True:
                print('found at index',i,j)
```

This program will check for 1 in the matrix and if it encounters 1 then it checks it's adjacent elements for 1 and if all are 1 then it will return True else it will return False.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over lines and cells, and for each top left corner, check if a square of cells all equal to 1, and return True if it does:

```
def has_square(seq):
    for row, line in enumerate(seq[:-1]):
        for col, cell in enumerate(line[:-1]):
            if cell == 1:
                if seq[row][col+1] == 1 and seq[row+1][col] == 1 and seq[row+1][col+1] == 1:
                    return True
    return False
```

#### Has square == True:

```
seq = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

has_square(seq)
```

#### Has square == False:

```
seq = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

has_square(seq)
```

It is rather crude, and does not generalize well, but does what you wanted: to determine if a sequence of sequences has squares of four ones.

Comment: Thank you so much. Saved the day. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

What about making it easily customizable?

```
width = 5 # Width of grid
height = 5
square_w = 2 # Width of square you want found
square_h = 2
square_coords = []
avoid = [0] # This number doesn't count as a square
grid_list = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
             0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
             0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
             0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
             0, 0, 0, 0, 0] # Grid

# ONLY EDIT ABOVE /\ /\ /\

conv_list = []
for rep_h in range(height): # Convert grid
    conv_list += [[0] * width]
    for rep_w in range(width):
        conv_list[rep_h][rep_w] = grid_list[rep_h*width+rep_w]

for rep_h in range(height-square_h+1): # Find squares
    for rep_w in range(width-square_w+1):
        square_vis = True
        if not conv_list[rep_h][rep_w] in avoid:
            square_val = conv_list[rep_h][rep_w]
            for h in range(square_h):
                for w in range(square_w):
                    if conv_list[rep_h+h][rep_w+w] != square_val:
                        square_vis = False
            if square_vis:
                square_coords += [[rep_h, rep_w]]

print(square_coords) # Print result (Starting coordinates, AKA top left of box found)
```